# Loading a module with a dependent class

Tags: python, class, import, module

I am new to Python and I apologize if I'm not using the proper vernacular in writing this question.  I'm using Python 3.6.1 on a Windows machine. I provide a working example of the problem I'm having.

Suppose I write a module saved in the file Demo_func.py. It contains the following function:

```
def chebyshev_nodes(degree, domain):
    return Chebyshev.basis(degree,domain).roots()
```

I then run the following script:

```
from numpy.polynomial.chebyshev import Chebyshev
from Demo_func import chebyshev_nodes

chebyshev_nodes(5, [1,5])
```

It produces this error:

> NameError: name 'Chebyshev' is not defined

If instead I write the function chebyshev_nodes within my script as below, then it works just fine.

```
from numpy.polynomial.chebyshev import Chebyshev
def chebyshev_nodes(degree, domain):
    return Chebyshev.basis(degree,domain).roots()

chebyshev_nodes(5, [1,5])
```

My understanding is that importing Chebyshev is global. But somehow, that does operate within my module Demo_func. How can I write a module that depends on Chebyshev class?

Comment: "My understanding is that importing Chebyshev is global" - it's not. The module initialization it performs is global, but it only makes the `Chebyshev` name available to the scope that performed the import.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Importing Chebyshev within the function definition works. Is that the proper way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

As user2357112 points out in a comment above, the the module is initialized globally but the name is not. The solution involves loading the Chebyshez class in the function in the  Demo_func.py file.

```
def chebyshev_nodes(degree, domain):
    from numpy.polynomial.chebyshev import Chebyshev
    return Chebyshev.basis(degree,domain).roots()
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this is a wrong answer. While it will work, there is no reason to import `Chebyshev` inside function body. It can and should be imported in the scope of module `Demo_func`. There is no circular import problem in this example, so workarounds like import in function body only obfuscate the code. And circular imports indicate that project layout is poorly designed anyway. Don't get me wrong. I'm not going to provide another answer to gain reputation. Put the import where it should be (cause you know it) and then I change my -1 into +1.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the answer tag. I don't case about virtual reputation. I provided a response because I hate leaving things undone.

I'm still in the process of learning how classes, scopes and namespaces, mostly by trials and errors. I understand from your comment that I can import `Chebyshev` at the top the the `Demo_func.py`file. It works and this is cleaner as you say. I had tried that before but I think it did not work because I had not restarted the kernel. Lesson learned.